# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar la ruta de un proyecto ya creado en Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Creé un proyecto en el escritorio, luego lo moví a una carpeta específica para todos mis proyectos de Android y así ordenar mis proyectos, pero la app ahora no me abre en el emulador.

Anteriormente me pasó y lo solucioné copiando y pegando el código en un proyecto nuevo, pero no es la idea. Quisiera poder tener un proyecto y poder moverlo al directorio que yo quiera sin estropearlo.

Este error me aparece cuando le doy clic a "Run App":
[image: Error que aparece cuando intento le doy a "Run App"]

Justo después, la consola de errores me marca esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
OBSERVACIÓN: En la segunda línea que se expande a la derecha, se escribe las ruta de:

- ~\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_5.apk
- ~\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_7.apk
- ~\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_0.apk
- ~\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_0.apk (cambia la primera parte de la ruta)
- ~\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\dep\dependencies.apk
- ~\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_2.apk

...muchos similares y luego...

- ~\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk

Comment: Sería muy útil para la comunidad si agregaras imágenes de lo que deseas, incluso que agregaras lo que has tratado. Te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**

Comment: En está página te explica como, ya solucione ese error. https://www.flipandroid.com/cmo-mover-y-renombrar-un-proyecto-en-android-studio.html